# How to publish x86 folder Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, wcf, deployment, visual-studio-2008, publish

I finished my project on visual studio 2008 which works only 32 bit application.
I changed configuration manager to x86 then VS created `/bin/x86/` folder application built successfully.
When I try to publish, it goes created `/debug/` folder automatically then copy all files to server /any cpy - exe files/.
The problem is I want to publish app files from only `/x86/`  folder. How to select that folder to publish it on server?
Sorry for poor english. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I deleted `x64` aslo `AnyCpy` each project and it works thanks.
It could maybe helps someone.
If you want to built for just x86 then you have to CONF editor > edit > delete x64 and all
that's all